# when using jquery to change the div content the form action in the div taking to the main page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am using jquery to change my div contents in the main.php file without refreshing the page,
but issue here is in the new div which is loaded contains a form, in the form action i want the form to be submitted to the same page(div) , but am redirected to the main.php which i don't want. What changes i have to make to the action to stay on the same page with the same div.

This is the code which i use to dynamically change the div.

main.php:

```
<li id="nav-home"><a class="button" href="main.php">Home</a></li>
<li id="nav-page1"><a class="button" href="page1.php">Page1</a></li>    
<li id="nav-page2"><a class="button" href="page2.php">Page2</a></li>
<li id="nav-page3"><a class="button" href="page3.php">Page3</a></li>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.button').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
        });
    })
</script>
```

example: when i click on the Page1 in the main.php the div content is being replace by the page1 where in page1 i have a form, when i submit the form i want to stay in the same page.

this is the code which handles the form in the page1:

```
<form name="form" id="form" method="POST" action=""> //my form elements </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#form").validate({
                debug: false,
                rules: {

                    //rules
                },
                messages: {

                    //messages
                },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    // do other stuff for a valid form
                    $.post('scripts/formhandler.php', $("#form").serialize(), function(data) {
                        $('#results').html(data);
                    });
                }
            });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the form.submit function, and handle the submit in there using ajax

```
$('#form_id').submit(function() 
{
     e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form action 

     /*now add ajax code here to do form submit*/
});
```

Of course if you're loading the form after the page has already been loaded, you would need to use the jquery.live or jquery.on function to set the form handler instead of the above code. Example:

```
$('#form_id').on('submit', function()
{
    // Code in here
});
```

You can read up more on .live and .on from the jquery site

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using validate plugin, and you can use the `ajaxSubmit` method which will basically wrap a submit call with preventDefault, handle all the form serialization, etc.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate

i.e.

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
  $(form).ajaxSubmit();
}
```

Comment: hi Can u please elaborate the solution on my issue am not so good at jquery.

Comment: revised answer.  But please look at the docs in the URL as well.